# Condensing/abstracting the path shown on each line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've started using virtualenv for my Python projects. Since the working directory for my projects is now deeply nested, the path has started to take up half of  my screen!

Is it possible to somehow have PowerShell condense the path to the current working directory, from something like `PS C:\Users\kRON\Desktop\Current work\Python\dsp\src>` to `PS C:\Users\kRON\Deskto~1\Curren~2\Python\dsp\src>` or, better yet, to match `C:\Users\kRON\Desktop\Current work\Python`and just replace it with `~python` to get `PS ~python\dsp\src>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Given a function or cmdlet to summarise the path, this can be used in your prompt function or in format files.

E.g. TFS PowerToys does this with a helper it installs using a `<scriptBlock>` in its `.format.xml` file.

Comment: The prompt function, so that's what it's called. Great ^^!